# Double entry with same info but in two columns in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a big database where the data is like this:

[image: Database data]

Now, I just want to get the info for unique values (for me `Steve-Kevin` is the same as `Kevin-Steve`, I can just take any one of them). How can I sort them in a way to get the unique value?

Comment: So is `Kevin-Steve` a duplicate that you can effectively delete out of the data, keeping `Steve-Kevin`?

Comment: Exactly, I want to effectively delete out the Kevin-Steve and want to work with the data associated with Steve-Kevin only. That is where I am stuck now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy with two *"helper"* columns.  Say we have:

[image]

In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<B2,A2,B2) & "-" & IF(A2<B2,B2,A2)
```

and copy downward.  *(column **D** shows the data combined in "alphabetic" order)*

In **E2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D2,D2)>1,"X","")
```

and copy downward *(column **E** marks duplicated records)*:

[image]

Now you can filter out those *"X"* rows.

Answer (score 0):

Tough one.  This formula will provide a numeric index that is the sum of the ASCII value (case sensitive) for the first 4 characters of each pair.  Should get you very close to correct sort order.

=CODE(A1)+CODE(B1)+CODE(MID(A1,2,1))+CODE(MID(B1,2,1))+CODE(MID(A1,3,1))+CODE(MID(B1,3,1))+CODE(MID(A1,4,1))+CODE(MID(B1,4,1))